# Remove a trailing slash from a string(changed from url type) in JAVA

Tags: java, url, slash, trailing

I want to remove the trailing slash from a string in Java.

I want to check if the string ends with a url, and if it does, i want to remove it.

Here is what I have:

```
String s = "http://almaden.ibm.com/";

s= s.replaceAll("/","");
```

and this:

```
String s = "http://almaden.ibm.com/";
length  =  s.length();
--length;
Char buff = s.charAt((length);
if(buff == '/')
{
     LOGGER.info("ends with trailing slash");
/*how to remove?*/
}
else  LOGGER.info("Doesnt end with trailing slash");
```

But neither work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can achieve this with [Apache Commons StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#removeEnd-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) as follows:

```
String s = "http://almaden.ibm.com/";
StringUtils.removeEnd(s, "/")
```

Comment: Far more concise with added benefits of null safety. Upvoted.

Answer (score 102):

There are two options: using pattern matching (slightly slower):

```
s = s.replaceAll("/$", "");
```

or:

```
s = s.replaceAll("/\\z", "");
```

And using an if statement (slightly faster):

```
if (s.endsWith("/")) {
    s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
}
```

or (a bit ugly):

```
s = s.substring(0, s.length() - (s.endsWith("/") ? 1 : 0));
```

Please note you need to use `s = s...`, because Strings are immutable.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Can i know if i could perform the same operation on a variable type URL, as i want to declare it as final.

replaceAll doesnt seem to work on type URL

Thanks for the replies again , i am a beginner in java !

Comment: `java.net.URL` can be converted to a `java.lang.String` using `toString()`.

Answer (score 18):

This should work better:

```
url.replaceFirst("/*$", "")
```

Comment: This removes multiple trailing slashes which I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

`url.replaceAll("/$", "")` the `$` matches the end of a string so it replaces the trailing slash if it exists.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Can i know if i could perform the same operation on a variable type URL, as i want to declare it as final.

replaceAll doesnt seem to work on type URL

Thanks for the replies again , i am a beginner in java !

Answer (score 8):

simple method in java

```
String removeLastSlash(String url) {
    if(url.endsWith("/")) {
        return url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/"));
    } else {
        return url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, though you don't need the else statement.

Answer (score 2):

As its name indicates, the replaceAll method replaces all the occurrences of the searched string with the replacement string. This is obviously not what you want. You could have found it yourself by reading [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).

The second one is closer from the truth. By reading the javadoc of the String class, you'll find a useful method called substring, which extracts a substring from a string, given two indices.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way ...

```
String yourRequiredString = myString.subString(0,myString.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

Comment: This should be myString.substring, not .subString .

Answer (score 2):

a more compact way:

> String pathExample = "/test/dir1/dir2/";
>
> String trimmedSlash = pathExample.replaceAll("^/|/$","");

regexp ^/ replaces the first,  /$  replaces the last

Answer (score 1):

If you are a user of **Apache Commons Lang** you can take profit of the *chomp* method located in *StringUtils*

> String s = "http://almaden.ibm.com/";
>
> StringUtils.chomp(s,File.separatorChar+"")

Comment: Two-argument method is deprecated in favor of `removeEnd`: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#removeEnd-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0):

### Kotlin side

```kotlin
    fun removeTrailSlash(s: String): String {
        return s.replace(Regex("/$"), "")
    }

    fun String.removeTrailSlash(): String {
        return CommonUtil.removeTrailSlash(this)
    }
```

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun removeTrailSlash() {
        // given
        val expected = "asdf/qwer"
        val s = "$expected/"
        // when
        val actual = CommonUtil.removeTrailSlash(s)
        // then
        assertEquals(expected, actual)
    }
    
    @Test
    fun removeTrailSlash() {
        // given
        val expected = "asdf/qwer"
        val s = "$expected/"
        // when
        val actual = s.removeTrailSlash()
        // then
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, actual)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   if (null != str && str.length > 0 )
    {
        int endIndex = str.lastIndexOf("/");
        if (endIndex != -1)  
        {
            String newstr = str.subString(0, endIndex); // not forgot to put check if(endIndex != -1)
        }
    }
```