# Remove string after last slash in JAVA

Tags: java, url

I have a problem with removing everything after the last slash of URL in JAVA
For instance, I have URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

n' I wanna change it to:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/
```

How can I do it.

Comment: Have you tried anything? At least gone through the String API?

Comment: Use String.lastIndexOf(String) to find the last slash and then select the substring till there...? Takes about 10 seconds to find in the String API...

Comment: one line solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437158/remove-a-trailing-slash-from-a-stringchanged-from-url-type-in-java/27942845#27942845

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can try this

```
    String str="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
    int index=str.lastIndexOf('/');
    System.out.println(str.substring(0,index));
```

Comment: how can i get string after third slash in java?

Comment: @Shaonline can I see your code pls?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37138900/how-to-fetch-string-after-the-third-slash-in-java

Comment: @Shaonline this question already has an answer. didn't it work for you?

Comment: Yeah i just got it... It works :) Thank you

Comment: thx @RuchiraGayanRanaweera , upvoted for a neat and clean solution.

Answer (score 20):

IF you want to get the last value from the uRL

```
String str="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
System.out.println(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/")));
```

Result will be "/ask"

If you want value after last forward slash

```
String str="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
System.out.println(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
```

Result will be "ask"

Answer (score 6):

Try using [String#lastIndexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29)

> Returns the index within this string of the last occurrence of the specified character.

```
String result = yourString.subString(0,yourString.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

Comment: also as a regular expression \/[^\/]*$

Comment: @ns47731. Which is really not needed here.

Comment: @RohitJain Your right definitely overkill

Comment: Yes,I always go for regex when only there is no  built-in methods available.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ How to print the characters after the last slash. for ex `String result=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` , ask in the string `result`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (null != str && str.length > 0 )
{
    int endIndex = str.lastIndexOf("/");
    if (endIndex != -1)  
    {
        String newstr = str.subString(0, endIndex); // not forgot to put check if(endIndex != -1)
    }
}
```