# How to fetch string after the third slash in java

Tags: java, substring, indexof

I am trying to fetch the string after the third slash. But i don' know how to do it. I have used split but that's not what I want.

```
for(String obj2: listKey.getCommonPrefixes()){
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[] id = obj2.split("/");
    if (id.length > 3) {
        String name = id[3];
        map.put("id", name);
        map.put("date", "null");
        map.put("size", String.valueOf(obj2.length()));
        keys.add(map);
    }
}
```

`id[3]` gives me only `id[3]` but i want everything after the third slash? how can i do that?

Comment: Can you show your input, the value of obj2 before the split?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can replace

```
 String[] id = obj2.split("/");
```

by

```
 String[] id = obj2.split("/", 4);
```

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) :

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.